# Is there is any possibilty for binding array in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

Service module:

```js
  baseurl: string = 'https://fireman-7cc06-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'

  getFunction(): Observable<object> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl + 'items.json')
  }
```

Component module:

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.itemservices.getFunction().subscribe(data => {
      this.listItems= data
     
      console.log(this.listItems)
      
    }, err => {
      console.log('error' + err)
    })
  }
```

View:

```html
<div *ngIf="listItems">
    <ul *ngFor="let info of listItems">
        <li>{{info.Item_name}}</li>
       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? you want to show the `listItems` array items inside the HTML?

Comment: Actually Iam getting error like=> core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Your API is not returning an array

Comment: You can use "Object.entries(object)" its convert object to array

Comment: Check this stackblitz demo "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rejmqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts"

Comment: I will check,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates `*ngFor` could only loop through iterables like an array. However your API returns an object. Ideally any data conversions must be done in the backend. However, if you so desire, you have the following options in the frontend.

#### Option 1: convert object to array

You could use JS `Object.values()` with RxJS `map` operator to fetch the values of the object as an array.

```js
const input = {"-MhJ49AIHh-53nnF07a1":{"Item_color":"white","Item_name":"amma","Item_price":"369","Item_type":"human"},"-MhJXlVgPBdZ6Q7L0Tnn":{"Item_color":"red","Item_name":"manu","Item_price":"1000","Item_type":"sunny"},"-MhJa9Xzmdq9OvkZyVN7":{"Item_color":"yellow","Item_name":"chinnu","Item_price":"500000","Item_type":"sunny"}}
console.log(Object.values(input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

baseurl: string = 'https://fireman-7cc06-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'

getFunction(): Observable<object> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + 'items.json').pipe(
    map((res: any) => Object.values(res))
  );
}
```

#### Option 2: use Angular `keyvalue` pipe

You could skip the conversion in using `Object.values()` and use the `keyvalue` pipe in component template to iterate through an object.

**Service**

```js
baseurl: string = 'https://fireman-7cc06-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'

getFunction(): Observable<object> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + 'items.json')
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<div *ngIf="listItems">
  <ul *ngFor="let info of listItems | keyvalue">
    <li>{{info?.value?.Item_name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are trying to loop through an object instead of array. Please check how you define **this.listItems**.

Declare it as array and assign the values accordingly. Then you should be able to loop through in html code.

```
listItems = [];
```